# Dissimilarity only between different treatments in dataset

Tags: distance, ecology, diversity, vegan

I am studying the impact of wildfires on vegetation species composition. I have surveyed the burnt and unburnt areas on six sites which burned at different points in time from which I now have species abundance data, in the form of a matrix (plots as rows, species as columns)

I'm interested in the dissimilarity between the burnt and unburnt plots at each site, and I would like to see if this changes over time. The hypothesis is that a recently burnt area has high dissimilarity from the adjecent unburnt area, but that this dissimilarity decreases with time since fire as the vegetation regenerates.

I know I can use eg. the **vegdist** function in **Vegan** in R to get eg. Bray-Curtis dissimilarity. But the result matrix that this returns is not very useful as it gives me the dissimilarity between ALL plots with all other plots (burnt-burnt, unburnt-unburnt and burnt-unburnt), and I am only interested in half of the resulting matrix (burnt-unburnt).

I'd like to plot the results of dissimilarity between all burnt and unburnt plots at each site as a simple linear regression and then test the change over time, with a simple linear regression. **The attached image** is me having done this, sort of, but after a lot of work where I've sorted the vegdist result in excel, removing all undesirable quadrat combinations. There MUST be an easier way to do this! Can't I tell R what my groups (treatments) are, and have it show me the dissimilarity for only the desirable combinations? I need to do this on a few other datasets, and I don't want to do it this way every time.

I guess I can do eg. an NMDS test get the centroids for each treatment at each site, and then look if the distance between them changes with time, but if I test the significance of that it will be a very low sample size, compared to if i test all pairwise comparisons (so I'm assuming that might not be good enough but maybe I'm wrong). Do you have any advice on how to do this? I hope my explanation makes sense.

[image: all pairwise comparisions of dissimilarity between treatments]

Comment: It is still unclear what exactly you seek to do, and whether this is a data analysis or a data manipulation question. Can you show a peace of data, and what you managed to do and what you wanted but couldn't do.

Comment: I can't tell from what you've written - do you have multiple burnt and un-burnt plots per site? Or just one pair per site? This does sound like more of an R data manipulation question, better suited to Stack Overflow.

Comment: In general, I'd be very cautious about interpreting a chart like the one shown in your question. Can all those points with the same x value really be considered independent - if not you need to account for it before testing the slope? One unusual site could have a huge impact on the analysis, because of all the bray-curtis values it generates

Comment: @rw2 yes you are absolutely right. It's just a bunch of pseudoreplication. In the end I did something completely else than above, I averaged the species composition for each site and then calculated Bray Curtis just between each pair of site I was interested in. Problem now is that when I plot this in an NMDS it doesn't at all show what I'd expect! Dissimilar and similar sites are plotted approximately at the same distance from each other. I have two sites with Bray dissimilarity = 0.9, extremely dissimilar, but they are ploted very near each other...

Comment: @user340096 That sounds like a plotting issue - maybe open a new question, with a reproducible example, and I'm sure somebody can help you. Again, it may be better suited to Stack Overflow.